# Mocha 'this' in before and beforeEach hooks

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

The following test code, written using [Mocha.js](http://mochajs.org/) fails. I expect the *someVal* to be increased 3 times and equal 3 in the last test. The issue came up in more complex scenario where I used value set in outer *before* block to set up another in inner *beforeEach* block. Simplified case:

```
describe('increasing 3 times', function() {
  before(function() {
    this.instanceThis = this;
    return this.someVal = 0;
  });
  beforeEach(function() {
    return this.someVal += 1;
  });
  return describe('going deeper', function() {
    before(function() {
      return this.someVal += 1;
    });
    beforeEach(function() {
      return this.someVal += 1;
    });
    return it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
      return this.someVal.should.equal(3);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Explanation

I don't know of *any* version of Mocha that would run the code you show in your question without error. For your code to work, it would have to be written like this:

```
require("chai").should();

describe('increasing 3 times', function() {
    before(function() {
        this.someVal = 0;
    });
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.someVal += 1;
    });
    describe('going deeper', function() {
        var parent_ctx = this.parent.ctx;
        before(function() {
            parent_ctx.someVal += 1;
            // The line above is equivalent to this:
            // this.test.parent.ctx.someVal += 1;
        });
        beforeEach(function() {
            parent_ctx.someVal += 1;
        });
        it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
            parent_ctx.someVal.should.equal(3);
            // The above line is equivalent to this:
            // this.test.parent.parent.ctx.someVal.should.equal(3);
        });
    });
});
```

Inside the function passed to `describe` and the functions passed to the hooks of a `describe` block (`before`, `beforeAll`, etc.) the value of `this` is a "context" object which is the same for the `describe` and all of its *own* hooks (not the hooks of *other* `describe` calls nested in it). So when you assign to `this`, it assigns to the *context*. If you want to access this context inside nested calls to `describe` or in tests you have to walk up the tree of `describe` and test objects.

#### Solution

I would do it exactly the same way Second Rikudo suggested: use a variable scoped to your uppermost `describe` call. For the sake of completeness:

```
require("chai").should();

describe('increasing 3 times', function() {
    var someVal;
    before(function() {
        someVal = 0;
    });
    beforeEach(function() {
        someVal += 1;
    });
    describe('going deeper', function() {
        before(function() {
            someVal += 1;
        });
        beforeEach(function() {
            someVal += 1;
        });
        it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
            someVal.should.equal(3);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The explanation is supported officially by mocha in [Shared Behaviours](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours)

Answer (score 4):

`this` is not what you think it is. `this` gets redefined in every `function() {}` block (unless Mocha calls them in some specific way I'm not familiar with).

What you want is to use scope in your advantage:

```
describe('increasing 3 times', function() {
  var someVal; // Initialization.
  before(function() {
    someVal = 0; //No need to return from before()
  });
  beforeEach(function() {
    someVal += 1;
  });
  describe('going deeper', function() {
    before(function() {
      someVal += 1;
    });
    beforeEach(function() {
      someVal += 1;
    });
    return it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
      someVal.should.equal(3);
    });
  });
});
```

Also, you don't need to `return` so much. In fact, you almost never have to return in test code.

Comment: I'm writing mostly in coffeescript. This was output from compiler with some small modifications. When I write JS manually I don't return so much :)

Comment: My described behaviour worked up to version 1.18.2 but changed in 1.19.0 (after merging https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/1164/files). Now I'm thinking whether or how to make Mocha behave similarly as before.