# Mocha and the this context

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

So I have this code:

```
describe('main describe', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
      //this.prop === undefined
    });

    describe('sub', function() {
        it('should do something', function() {
            this.prop = 'test';
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know why `this.prop` in the `main` `afterEach` is `undefined` because the follow code work as expected:

```
describe('main describe', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
      //this.prop === 'test'
    });

    it('should do something', function() {
        this.prop = 'test';
    });
});
```

Why does the first code not work as I though it would where this.prop should equal `'test'` and not `undefined`?

Is the `this` keyword tied to only the `describe` function it is directly contained it?

Comment: For reference, these are the docs I could find: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours (as of now they don't answer this specific question though)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yep, each `describe` gets a new `Context` object. (All the classes I mention can be found in Mocha's source code.) You could get what you are trying to do with:

```
describe('main describe', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
        console.log(this.prop);
    });

    describe('sub', function() {
        it('should do something', function() {
            this.test.parent.ctx.prop = 'test';
        });
    });
});
```

The line `this.test.parent.ctx.prop` is the key. `this` is the `Context` associated with the `it` call. `this.test` is the `Test` object associated with the `it` call. `this.test.parent` is the `Suite` object associated with the `describe` call that immediately contains the `it` call. `this.test.parent.ctx` is the context in effect where the `describe` call *appears*, which happens to be the same context as `this` in the `afterEach` call.

I would actually recommend not traversing Mocha's internal structures and instead doing something like:

```
describe('main describe', function() {
    var prop;
    afterEach(function() {
        console.log(prop);
    });

    describe('sub', function() {
        it('should do something', function() {
            prop = 'test';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any idea why you have `this.test.parent.ctx` whereas https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363746/271577 lists `this.parent.ctx`, and https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours has just `this`, while https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2743#issue-214747482 lists `this.currentTest.ctx` and in some cases `this.ctx`. Are these aliases or...?

Comment: @BrettZamir I would not think of it in terms of *aliases*. The `this` set on a `describe` callback is not the same `this` as the one on an `it` callback or a `before` callback, etc. In the answer of mine you linked, the start point is a `describe` callback whereas here it is a `before` callback. Different starting points call for different paths. The other cases you link to are trying to get to different end points. It's similar to how people use different file paths because they are starting from a different directory or want to reach different files at the end.