# What does `this` point at in the following js arrow functions in mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, this

What does `this` point here?

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('test', () => {
  describe('test()', () => {
    afterEach(function _test() {
      this.xxx = undefined; // What does `this` point here?
    });
  });

  describe('test2()', () => {
    afterEach(function _test2() {
      this.yyy = undefined; // What does `this` point here?
    });
  });
});
```

By the way, it is good to use `this` in the above codes if both `this`(s) point at the same object?

**UPDATE**

Code

```
describe('test', () => {
  console.log(1, this);
  before(() => {
    console.log(2, this);
  });
  beforeEach( () => {
    console.log(3, this);
  });
  describe('going deeper', () => {
    console.log(4, this);
    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log(6, this);
    });
    return it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
      assert.equal(1,1);
      //console.log(7, this);
    });
  });
});
```

output:

```
1 {}
4 {}


  test
2 {}
    going deeper
3 {}
6 {}
      ✓ has increased someVal to 3


  1 passing (4ms)
```

code (changed one arrow function to normal function):

```
describe('test', () => {
  console.log(1, this);
  before(() => {
    console.log(2, this);
  });
  beforeEach( () => {
    console.log(3, this);
  });
  describe('going deeper', () => {
    console.log(4, this);
    beforeEach(function() { // HERE
      console.log(6, this);
    });
    return it('has increased someVal to 3', function() {
      assert.equal(1,1);
      //console.log(7, this);
    });
  });
});
```

output:

```
1 {}
4 {}


  test
2 {}
    going deeper
3 {}
      1) "before each" hook for "has increased someVal to 3"


  0 passing (6ms)
  1 failing

  1) test going deeper "before each" hook for "has increased someVal to 3":
     TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
      at Object.stringify (native)
      at formatValue (util.js:352:36)
      at inspect (util.js:186:10)
      at exports.format (util.js:72:24)
      at Console.log (console.js:43:37)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test3.js:32:15)
```

Comment: That would entirely depend on what test framework this is. It is the thing setting `this` because it is the thing calling the function.

Comment: It's whatever `this` is outside the outer `describe()` call.

Comment: I see your edit, which makes it seem like _probably_ Mocha?

Comment: Mocha does not call the `afterEach` callback with any particular this, so normal rules are followed.

Comment: @torazaburo Doesn't it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358338/mocha-this-in-before-and-beforeeach-hooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both locations you inquire about, `this` is bound by Mocha to an internal Mocha object. One thing this object allows you to do, for instance, is change Mocha's configuration. Like changing the timeout of asynchronous function with `this.timeout(newValue)`. It's not particularly useful in the example below, but Mocha will run it just fine. Eg:

```
describe('test', () => {
  describe('test()', () => {
    afterEach(function _test() {
      this.timeout(5000);
      this.xxx = undefined;
    });

    it("foo", () => {});
  });

  describe('test2()', () => {
    afterEach(function _test2() {
      this.timeout(5000);
      this.yyy = undefined;
    });

    it("foo", () => {});
  });
});
```

Note that if you were to use an arrow function for your `afterEach` callbacks, you could not access the value of `this` that Mocha sets for the callback. (`this` will have a value set in an outer scope.)

> By the way, it is good to use this in the above codes if both this(s) point at the same object?

I don't recommend setting arbitrary fields on `this`. There's no telling when the field you set is going to clash with a field introduced by a newer version of Mocha. I've always been able instead to set a variable in the enclosing `describe` and use that:

```
describe('test', () => {
    let something;

    beforeEach(function _test() {
        something = fetchATestFixtureFromSomewhere();
    });

    it("foo", () => {
        // use the variable something here.
    });
});
```

---

Regarding your update. Everywhere you get `{}` on the console that's because all functions enclosing your `console.log` are arrow functions and as I've said above, if you use an arrow function then *you cannot access the object that Mocha binds to `this`* because in such case `this` is taken from an outer scope instead of being taken from the value bound to the function. If all enclosing functions are arrow functions then `this` comes from the outermost scope and it has the value `{}` in the outermost scope.

The error you get is because you cannot just dump the value Mocha assigns to `this` to the console, because as the error message indicates, it is a structure with a circular reference in it.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question because it is something that is not addressed in a lot of arrow function tutorials.

Arrow functions have there "this" context bound at definition time, but more importantly your question. The this will inherit recursively.

```
describe('test', () => {                 // `this` is the global object
  describe('test()', () => {             // `this` is the global object
    afterEach(function _test() {        
      this.xxx = undefined;              // `this` is the global object
    });
  });

  describe('test2()', () => {            // `this` is the global object
    afterEach(function _test2() {        
      this.yyy = undefined;              // `this` is the global object
    });
  });
});
```

Here is an example

```js
 const foo = ()=>{
  console.log("foo is window?",this === window);
  const a = (input)=>{console.log("a is window?",this === window); this._=input }; 
  const b = ()=> {console.log("b is window?",this === window);return this._} 
  return { a,b }
 }

 const bar= foo()
 console.log(bar.b()) // undefined
 bar.a(5)
 console.log(bar.b()) // 5
 console.log(window._) // 5
```

if you change

```
const b = ()=> {console.log("b is window?",this === window);return this._}
```

to

```
const b = function() {console.log("b is window?",this === window);return this._}
```

the `this` now points to the wrapping Object `{ a,b }`

If you use an ES6 to ES5 ⚠ will replace `this` with `undefined`

```
"use strict"; // https://es6console.com/

var foo = function foo() {
    console.log("foo is window?", undefined === window);
    var a = function a(input) {
        console.log("a is window?", undefined === window);undefined._ = input;
    };
    var b = function b() {
        console.log("b is window?", undefined === window);return undefined._;
    };
    return { a: a, b: b };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. but what do you mean by `global object`?

Comment: I don't know that I think `context bound at definition time` is a good way to think about arrow functions. Non-arrows basically have an implicit `const this = ...` in them so usage of `this` in a non-arrow uses that variable. Arrow functions don't have that, so accessing `this` works just like any other variable, where it will use the one from the parent scope instead.

Comment: @<BAE> I say global object because if you're running in node it will be the process and if you are running in some other environment it may not be window

Comment: Your examples are wrong, `this` will never be `_test`. The Node global is also `global`, not `process`.