# mocha: setting varibles on `this` is antipattern?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am confused by the following two pieces of codes:

code1:

```
describe('suit', function(){
    before(() => {
        this.suitData = 'suitdata';
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.testData = 'testdata';
    });


    it('test', done => {
         console.log(this.suitData)// => suitdata
         console.log(this.testData)// => testdata
    })
});
```

code2:

```
describe('suit', function(){
    const suitData = 'suitdata';
    const testData = 'testdata';

    before(() => {
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
    });


    it('test', done => {
         console.log(suitData)// => suitdata
         console.log(testData)// => testdata
    })
});
```

which one is better, code1 or code2? I think code1 is kind of anti-pattern. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: I would always use the 2nd option and not the 1st one because then I don't even have to bother to find out what `this` is set to in a mocha test. Even if I happened to know I would have to consider other people who have to read this. The scoping rules of the 2nd example are globally valid (in the entire JS universe), but knowing what `this` is in the particular piece of code is knowledge specific to this particular tool (mocha), it's not reusable knowledge. -- Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27358338/544779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `this` to store values.

#### Risk of a Clash Between Mocha's Values and Yours

The `this` context already contains some values set by Mocha as part of its public API (`this.timeout`, for instance) and there are some values that are not formally documented but can be useful to use (`this.test`, for instance). If you set variables on `this` you may run into a clash with Mocha's variables. If you overwrite the `this.timeout` function with a string, for instance, then you cannot use call `this.timeout` if you want to change the timeout. In a large suite where you've been using `this.timeout` for your own purpose, it may be costly to fix the clash later. And there's the issue that a name that does not clash now, *may* clash in a future release of Mocha.

If you use closures as in your 2nd example, then there cannot be any clash.

#### Unexpected Behavior of `this`

Boneskull, one of the owners of Mocha on GitHub, said in a [comment](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2014#issuecomment-170150973):

> I would strongly urge users to not use `this` for storing values, ever.

This was in the context of an [issue report](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2014) that was showing unexpected results while using `this` to store values. Here's another [issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2914) about unexpected behavior regarding `this`. The way `this` is managed between tests is not something that has been documented, so people imagine that it'll work in a certain way, but it does not. The changes that would need to be made would require a new major version of Mocha.

Conversely, if you use scopes like in your second example, how the variables are created and changed is always crystal-clear from a) knowing JavaScript and b) reading the documentation of Mocha (because you need to know something about the order in which hooks and tests are run).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `this` "is not something that has been documented" - that's why I couldn't find documentation on that - and links to related issues. However this wiki page shows how to use `this` to share data : https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours - so that goes directly agains the recommendation of not using `this` for storing data.